# facing an issue while executing Xpath with Index code in APPIUM

Tags: java, appium

Appium logs patch:

```
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] [BOOTSTRAP LOG] [debug] Returning result: {"status":32,"value":"javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Extra illegal tokens: ')', '[', '2', ']'"}
[debug] [AndroidBootstrap] Received command result from bootstrap
[debug] [MJSONWP] Matched JSONWP error code 32 to InvalidSelectorError
[debug] [W3C (065be1bf)] Encountered internal error running command: InvalidSelectorError: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Extra illegal tokens: ')', '[', '2', ']'
```

Eclipse Code:

```
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    //to click on specific object/position on a screen
    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='Preference']").click();
    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.TextView[@text='3. Preference dependencies']").click();
    //finding element by ID
    driver.findElementById("android:id/checkbox").click();
    // 
    driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout)[2]").click();

    driver.findElementByClassName("//android.widget.EditText").sendKeys("Hello");
    driver.findElementsByClassName("android.widget.Button").get(1).click();
```

Till 3rd line, the code works and fine but at that, it stops and doesn't go to the next lines of code and shows the above error in Appium.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bracket is missing in the line `driver.findElementByXPath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout)[2]").click();`

If you are going to the 2nd index using the xpath, you need to add a bracket before starting the xpath like:

```
driver.findElementByXPath("(//android.widget.RelativeLayout)[2]").click();
```

Also, in the next line you are using className, and if you are using any tag like `id` or `className` while identifying the element then `//` is not used, so you need to change it to:

```
driver.findElementByClassName("android.widget.EditText").sendKeys("Hello");
```

else it will throw a `NoSuchElementException`.

Comment: thanks, @sameer-arora . It worked for me when I re-write the code and I got to see the mistakes and much appreciated for jumping in to resolve this issue.